# How can I display scroll bars in the left direction too?

Tags: css

I wrote the following code.

This code hoped to display scroll bars on both left and right.

However, in fact you can only scroll to the right.

- Is this behavior mentioned in the W3C specification?
- How can I scroll left and right?

```css
body {
  overflow: auto;
}

.box1 {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  left: -50px;
  background-color: red;
}

.box2 {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  right: -50px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="box1"></div>
<div class="box2"></div>
```

thank you.

Comment: Yes this is bydesign, you can sroll only the right .. any overflow on the left is lost

Comment: you cannot. scrollbar position/direction depends on the language direction of the document ( rtl/ltr). what overflows from the opposite direction is hidden and do not create a scrollbar.  But overflow could be handle a few other ways ;) https://www.w3.org/TR/2017/WD-css-overflow-4-20170613/

Comment: OK, I understood. So, what kind of means do you use when you want to do something like this? Even if JavaScript is used, can not it be realized?

Answer (score 1):

Like other comments said, left overflow is hidden "by design" but...

What you could do is leave the left element at position `left: 0;` and then position your right element out of the view port with `right: -100px;` after what you would need to calculate the width of the actual view port and the width of the scrollable area and automatically position the horizontal scrollbar using the formula `(scrollWidth - viewWidth) / 2`.

You can see the result by running the snippet below.

```js
// get view port width
const viewWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
// get scroll width
const scrollWidth = document.documentElement.scrollWidth;
// position horizontal scroll
document.documentElement.scrollLeft = (scrollWidth - viewWidth) / 2;
```

```css
body {
  overflow: auto;
}

.box1 {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  left: 0; /* modified value from -50px to 0 */
  background-color: red;
}

.box2 {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  right: -100px; /* modified value from -50px to -100px */
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="box1"></div>
<div class="box2"></div>
```